# CruiseControl CommunicationsException Object Reference Error

Tags: .net, frameworks, continuous-integration, virtual-machine, cruisecontrol.net

In CruiseControl version 1.6.7981.1 I am getting the error below from event viewer which caused the ccservice to stop. The work around that I have so far is logging into the build box and start ccservice manually. It looks like it is happening sporadically and I am not sure what is causing it nor do I find any information relating to this error in cruisecontrol.net documentation and site. If anyone know or can point me to the right direction relating to this error would be appreciated?

```
.NET Runtime version 2.0.50727.5466 - Fatal Execution Engine Error 80131506


2013-07-17 21:56:51,621 [MyProjectBuildNodes] ERROR CruiseControl.NET [(null)] - INTERNAL ERROR: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
----------
ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Remote.CommunicationsException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Remote.RemotingConnection.SendMessage(String action, ServerRequest request)
   at ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Remote.CruiseServerClient.GetProjectStatus()
   at ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.Triggers.ProjectTrigger.GetCurrentProjectStatus()
   at ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.Triggers.ProjectTrigger.Fire()
   at ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.Triggers.MultipleTrigger.Fire()
   at ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.ProjectIntegrator.PollTriggers()
   at ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.ProjectIntegrator.Integrate()
   at ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.ProjectIntegrator.Run()
----------
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After researching further below are the options to resolve this issue:

1. Re install the .Net Framework
2. Re install the application that leads to the error "*.NET Runtime version 2.0.50727.5466 - Fatal Execution Engine Error 80131506*". We identified this through the eventviewer and our application log
3. Install an update for your virtual machine host if you have your server running on virtual machine. This is supposedly to be a known issue.

We went through all the options and option 3 worked for us. It looked like this issue is caused by unexpected behavior in the virtual machine's monitor when set to Software Monitor mode.

Answer (score 2):

One causer of this exception is a non coinciding assembly version of CCNet Service and WebDashboard or any other Client that is connected to the CCNet Service (like the TrayApp, etc.).

You may also want to update all involved parts of CCNet to the latest Version 1.8.x.